# Not able to Transform T4 Template using MSBUILD toolset="16.0"

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, t4

I'm Trying to Transform T4 Template using MSBUILD , but I'm getting the following error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\TextTemplating\Micro
>   soft.TextTemplating.targets(224,5): error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the asse
>   mbly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Cores.dll
>   ". Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Curre
>   nt\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Cores.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. [E:\csha
>   rpprojects\Automateodessa\Automateodessa\Automateodessa.csproj]

My .tt file content

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 WriteLine($"Hello World {i}");
#>
Hello$(classname)
```

My .csproj file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="16.0">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <builtdir>E:\BuiltApp</builtdir>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{58C4A28E-C37D-4D95-BBEE-6427A3F3129D}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Automateodessa</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Automateodessa</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
   <T4ParameterValues Include="classname">
        <Value>asdsd</Value>
        <Visible>False</Visible>
    </T4ParameterValues>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{508349B6-6B84-4DF5-91F0-309BEEBAD82D}" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="TextTemplate1.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>TextTemplate1.txt</LastGenOutput>
    </Content>
    <Resource Include="TextTemplate1.txt">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>TextTemplate1.tt</DependentUpon>
    </Resource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="The output file is hhahah" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

And my command for MSbuild is

```
MSBuild.exe E:\csharpprojects\Automateodessa\Automateodessa\Automateodessa.csproj /t:Transform /p:TransformFile="TextTemplate1.tt"
```

Can Someone tell me why am I getting this error?

P.S
My MSBUILD Variable got by /v:diag

````
MSBuildBinPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin
MSBuildExtensionsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild
MSBuildExtensionsPath32 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild
MSBuildExtensionsPath64 = C:\Program Files\MSBuild
MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath32 = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath64 = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
MSBuildFrameworkToolsRoot = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\
MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly = true
MSBuildNodeCount = 1
MSBuildProgramFiles32 = C:\Program Files (x86)
MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets = Build
MSBuildProjectDirectory = E:\csharpprojects\StudySnippets
MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot = csharpprojects\StudySnippets
MSBuildProjectExtension = .csproj
MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath = E:\csharpprojects\StudySnippets\obj\
MSBuildProjectFile = Testing.csproj
MSBuildProjectFullPath = E:\csharpprojects\StudySnippets\Testing.csproj
MSBuildProjectName = Testing
MSBuildRuntimeType = Full
MSBuildRuntimeVersion = 4.0.30319
MSBuildSDKsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Sdks
MSBuildStartupDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin
MSBuildToolsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin
MSBuildToolsPath32 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin
MSBuildToolsPath64 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64
MSBuildToolsRoot = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild
MSBuildToolsVersion = Current
MSBuildUserExtensionsPath = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild
MSBuildVersion = 16.2.37902
MsTestToolsTargets = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0
\TeamTest\Microsoft.TeamTest.targets
NetFrameworkPropsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.NET
Framework.CurrentVersion.props
NetFrameworkTargetsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.N
ETFramework.CurrentVersion.targets```
````

Comment: Did you use Developer Command Prompt to build your project?

Comment: I did use the msbuild packed with VS19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not able to Transform T4 Template using MSBUILD toolset=“16.0”

I think you just use msbuild.exe from an old framework or just use an old version of MSBuild like VS2017. Since you have set `MSBUILD toolset="16.0"`, it means that you should use MSBuild v16.0 to build your project.

**1)** Please use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` rather than any other old version of MSBuild.exe

**2)** just use [Developer Command Prompt for VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs)

**Update 1**

**Besides**, if you still face the issue after the solution, I think there are something wrong with your project or VS Environment.

**Solution**

**1)** I think you have create a new VS2019 project and then migrate the old project into it to test whether it is your old project's problem.

**2)** Please [do a repair in VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update your VS to the latest version to test whether it is the issue of your VS Environment.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: I Still get the same error even after following the solution. I indeed was using the MSBUILD Packed with VS2019.

Comment: I think you just migrate this old project into VS2019. So please try to create a new  defaultvs2019 project and then add the t4 template to test whether it is an issue about the old project. Besides, [do a repair in vs installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to test whether the component has broken.

Comment: I Created the Project in VS2019 and added T4 , However updating VS to 16.4.5 got my issue solved. Thank you for your time